# How to plot the string with power of ten as the exponential?

Tags: python, matplotlib, significant-digits

I want to plot a scientific title or legend label which is e^(x*10**b).

Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = 5.55e10

plt.title('e$^{%.2e}$'%(data))
```

And, the actual output is:
[image: real]

The preferred output is:
[image: answer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the formatted string and format them again:

```
>>> val = 5.55e10
>>> base, power = f'{val:.2e}'.split('e')
>>> f'e$^{{{base}*10^{{{power}}}}}$'
'e$^{5.55*10^{+10}}$'
```

Output in matplotlib:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

data = 5.55e10

s = re.sub(r'e([+-]\d+)', r'\\cdot{}10^{\1}', f'e$^{{{data:.2e}}}$')

plt.title(s)
```

output:
[image]

Comment: For scientific counting, I think "\times"(×) is better than "\cdot"(·)

Comment: @MechanicPig I guess this is a matter of personal preference, I like the cdot. I use × for things like `100×`, `2×3 cm` ;)

Comment: It may be caused by differences in education. Chinese primary school textbooks will mention that the multiplication sign should not be replaced by a dot in pure numeric expressions :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by extracting the base and exp:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log10, floor



def find_exp_base(number):
    exp = floor(log10(abs(number)))
    return round(number/10**exp, 2), exp 

    
data = 5.55e10
base, exp = find_exp_base(data)

plt.title('e$^{' + str(base) + '*10^{'+ str(exp) + '}}$')
plt.show()
```

output :

[image]